# How to rescale 4 gaussian in order to make them sum to 1?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gaussian

I am producing this plot with ggplot2, here each Gaussian sum to 1 but I would like that all 4 together sum to 1 so that the density on y axis should be divided of 4. Anyone know how to do it? Here the code that I am using my "data" i a table with 1 column of distances and 1 column with the relative cluster.

```
p5 <- ggplot(data,aes(x=distances, fill=cluster)) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.25,adjust=4)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("seagreen2","darkseagreen2","palegreen4","palegreen1"))+
  xlab("distance (nm)")+theme_bw()
p5
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?geom_density` computed variables section, the `count` variable is the density * number of observations (for that group). Hence if we divide the `count` variable by their sum (total observations between all groups), we should get proportional densities.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- rbind(
  iris[1:75, ], # 50 setosa + 25 vericolor
  iris[101:111, ] # 10 virginica
)

ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note that if you want the divide the densities by the number of densities, you can use `after_stat(density / sum(density)))` (since every density sums to 1).

Comment: Hey You know also how can i make them trasparent?

Comment: Yeah just set the `alpha` in the density layer like you did in your own example.

Comment: I noticed that this is not working If my distribution contribute differently to the final result, do you know how can I Compute the weight of each component?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: Suppose that I have inside my data 4 cluster and I want to compute the weighted average mean of my data considering that maybe 1 cluster has more component that the other, So has an are behind the curve bigger than the another one.

Comment: The weighted average of what variable and weighted by what? Keep in mind that we don't have your data so we don't know what is going on with your data. If your data is not to be shared online, can you create a dummy example that explains the problem?

Comment: I have a data frame in which I have 2 column  Column1(Cluster)-> 2,3,1,3,4 Column2(with Distances)->35,34,38,40,45 and for example I want to compute the average mean with respect to the number of cluster. But I think I got it so thank you a lot anyaway

Comment: How does one scale by custom coefficient? For example, I would like to graph a zero-inflated distribution. I have a "dot" at zero, and then I would like to rescale the density to add up to 1-Prob(x==0)