# What is the difference between the density function in Python and in R?

Tags: python, r, plot, difference, density-plot

I am representing the density function both in R and in python but I get very different graphs.

In this case a continuous variable (`var A`) segmented by a binomial variable (`TARGET`) is represented.

In R:

```r
ggplot(df,aes(x=varA))+
  geom_density(aes(fill=as.factor(TARGET)), alpha=0.8,position="identity")
```

[image: R density plot]

In Python:

```py
sns.displot(data=df, x="varA", kind="kde",hue='TARGET',fill=True,alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Python density plot]

I hope someone knows what the difference is. If I had to choose between the two, I would go with the python option, because I know that the data set is highly unbalanced in favor of `TARGET=0` with a 24/1 ratio.

PS: Here is an extract of the original dataset with 75 samples so that you can try to use it as an example. I hope you find it useful.

```r
#For R
varA = c(117465.649016494, 49063.16, 187301.12, 130446.8, 68198.33, 117465.649016494, 59047.7, 44807.54, 176584.67, 173465.48, 84359.27, 117465.649016494, 42990.02, 108058.61, 83574.29, 42434.06, 65527.43, 117465.649016494, 113690.81, 52180.73, 140531.33, 58764.83, 132205.55, 70914.83, 93725.3, 117465.649016494, 86263.1, 117465.649016494, 62872.61, 117465.649016494, 89739.02, 72971, 179974.64, 107082.38, 117465.649016494, 126198.83, 72296.51, 60983.69, 237160.67, 125980.82, 169083.53, 128323.43, 160592.33, 48822.47, 225651.29, 77612.84, 55339.1, 94338.68, 64148.03, 32315.63, 210103.91, 117465.649016494, 111579.29, 117465.649016494, 117465.649016494, 41742.14, 74848.46, 159631.46, 136571.42, 154994.9, 117465.649016494, 108487.16, 75045.83, 59831.18, 103325.75, 117465.649016494, 36725.09, 128741.18, 59532.08, 117465.649016494, 29905.13, 169864.76, 210531.8, 114727.76, 71640.71)
TARGET = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df = data.frame(varA,TARGET)
```

```py
#For python
varA = [117465.649016494, 49063.16, 187301.12, 130446.8, 68198.33, 117465.649016494, 59047.7, 44807.54, 176584.67, 173465.48, 84359.27, 117465.649016494, 42990.02, 108058.61, 83574.29, 42434.06, 65527.43, 117465.649016494, 113690.81, 52180.73, 140531.33, 58764.83, 132205.55, 70914.83, 93725.3, 117465.649016494, 86263.1, 117465.649016494, 62872.61, 117465.649016494, 89739.02, 72971, 179974.64, 107082.38, 117465.649016494, 126198.83, 72296.51, 60983.69, 237160.67, 125980.82, 169083.53, 128323.43, 160592.33, 48822.47, 225651.29, 77612.84, 55339.1, 94338.68, 64148.03, 32315.63, 210103.91, 117465.649016494, 111579.29, 117465.649016494, 117465.649016494, 41742.14, 74848.46, 159631.46, 136571.42, 154994.9, 117465.649016494, 108487.16, 75045.83, 59831.18, 103325.75, 117465.649016494, 36725.09, 128741.18, 59532.08, 117465.649016494, 29905.13, 169864.76, 210531.8, 114727.76, 71640.71]
TARGET = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(varA, TARGET)),
               columns =['varA', 'TARGET'])
```

thanks for everything guys...

Comment: It looks like ggplot2 has each groups density sum to one, whereas for python it is summed overall. (of course there could be other differences over type of kernel and bandwidth selection).

Comment: you could try the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091199/how-to-rescale-4-gaussian-in-order-to-make-them-sum-to-1

Comment: If you gave us a [mcve] we could tell whether this was really a duplicate or not (by trying the answer linked by @user20650)